# How to use post method in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
     constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {text: this.props.navigation.state.params.text,
    name:this.props.navigation.state.params.name};
      }

    manage = () => {

    Alert.alert('done')
      Actions.reset('mainScreen');

    fetch("http://ip/api/confirm", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({

        name: this.props.navigation.state.params.name,
        text:this.props.navigation.state.params.text
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())

      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });

    }
```

i want to do this

when i press in button go to manage function 
and post the text and the name to my api i dont know how can i pass them

> its give me this error :
>    network request failed

any help please

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to make network requests.

Installing:

```
npm i -S axios
```

Performing a POST request:

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios({
    url: 'http://ip/api/confirm',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      name: this.props.navigation.state.params.name,
      text: this.props.navigation.state.params.text,
    },
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: @dodoyousef please try `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` to test code functionality

Answer (score 0):

```
 var resp = await manage(this.props.session.userId,this.props.session.ApiKey,"hi","hello");
      if (resp.status == 200){
         var respBody = await resp.json();
        console.log('Fetch Todo response '+respBody); 
      }
```

API in separate file

```
export async function manage(userId,ApiKey,query,query1) {

  var url ="http://www.example.com/getdata";

  const params = {
    search:query,
    searches:query1
  };


  var formBody = [];
for (const property in params) {
const encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(params[property]);
  formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
}

formBody = formBody.join("&");


const requestOptions = {
'method': 'POST',
'headers': {
   'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  // 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
'body': formBody

};

  requestOptions.headers["userid"] = userId
  requestOptions.headers["apikey"] = ApiKey

  try {
    var resp = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
    return resp;
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
    return err;
  }
}
```